# Is there a way to override a closure in a Spock test?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

While this is specific to Jenkins code this question I think is more generally about the metaprogramming features of Groovy.

This is what my tests looks like:

```
// MyDeclarativePipelineTest.groovy
class MyDeclarativePipelineTest extends DeclarativePipelineTest {
  @Override
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    helper.registerAllowedMethod("parameters", [ArrayList.class], null)
  }
}

// someTests.groovy
class someTests extends MyDeclarativePipelineTest {
  @Override
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
  }

  @Test
  public void pipeline_should_execute_without_errors() throws Exception {
    addParam('MYPARAM', 'sdfsdfsdf')

    def script = loadScript("Jenkinsfile")
    script.run()
    assertJobStatusSuccess()
  }
}

// Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                If(true) {print("sdfsdfsd")} // should fail because not wrapped in script{} step
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this library in my Spock tests: [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit)

I want to overrided the steps{} closure in my MyDeclarativePipelineTest class

The steps closure is defined in this class [StageDeclaration.groovy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/blob/6e94552bed1505958199f1563e6509a9f7e74f6a/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/declarative/StageDeclaration.groovy#L63)

StageDeclaration is used in the [GenericPipelineDeclaration](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/blob/6e94552bed1505958199f1563e6509a9f7e74f6a/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/declarative/GenericPipelineDeclaration.groovy) class like this:

```
def stage(String name,
          @DelegatesTo(strategy = DELEGATE_FIRST, value = StageDeclaration) Closure closure) {
    this.stages.put(name, createComponent(StageDeclaration, closure).with { it.name = name; it })
}
```

And then finally the GenericPipelineDeclaration is used in [DeclarativePipelineTest](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/blob/a698b6a7977a588d227fc73de285506f6d7f7a6e/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/declarative/DeclarativePipelineTest.groovy) like this:

```
def pipelineInterceptor = { Closure closure ->
    GenericPipelineDeclaration.binding = binding
    GenericPipelineDeclaration.createComponent(DeclarativePipeline, closure).execute(delegate)
}
```

I'm extending DeclarativePipelineTest with my own class MyDeclarativePipelineTest

Is there a way I can override the steps closure inside of MyDeclarativePipelineTest? I want it to throw an error if raw Groovy code is defined in the `steps{}` closure that isn't wrapped in a `script{}` closure.

Comment: A quick reminder rd888 that your spelling needs correction with nearly every post. Could I trouble you to start using a spell checker?

Comment: not sure if this would be helpful to you: https://ideone.com/9Jgbis
I am not really able to understand why @Override is no solution here.